# JQuery Validator with custom .addMethod over Bootstrap gives problems when was-validated class is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having some troubles with Bootstrap 5 and JQuery Validator with custom class.

Seems it works separately from Bootstrap.

In this method for checking hex validity (optional) the `.was-validated` form class generates problems.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isvalidhex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null;
}, "Must be a valid hex");
```

Here my code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>form * { text-align:center; }</style>


<form method="POST" class="needs-validation" id="formAA" novalidate="novalidate">

<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="a" class="form-label">A</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-center" id="a" name="a" maxlength="100" required="">
</div>
<div class="divdropdowncolor mb-3 text-center">
  <label for="selectcolor" class="form-label">B</label><br>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="color" id="selectcolor" name="selectcolor" value="#0AF000" style="display:inline-block; width:48%; vertical-align: middle; float:left;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-center error" id="selectcolorB" name="selectcolorB" placeholder="#FFFFFF" maxlength="7" style="display:inline-block; width:48%; vertical-align: middle; float:right;" col="7" aria-invalid="true">
</div>
<div class="mb-3" style="clear:both;"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control-lg" style="width:100%;">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- scripts -->
<script>
function isValidColor(str) { return str.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null; }
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectcolorB').val($('#selectcolor').val());
});
$('#selectcolor').on('change', function (event) { $('#selectcolorB').val($('#selectcolor').val()); });
$('#selectcolorB').on('change', function (event) { if( isValidColor($('#selectcolorB').val()) ) { $('#selectcolor').val($('#selectcolorB').val()); } });
</script>

<script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("isvalidhex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null;
}, "Must be a valid hex");

$('#formAA').validate({

  rules: {
    selectcolorB : { isvalidhex : true },
    bgcolor : { isvalidhex : true }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form, e) {
    console.log('The form is valid and would have been submitted successfully');
  }
});
</script>

<script>
(function () {
  'use strict'
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
            //form.classList.remove('was-validated')
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
</script>
```

It's more complicated said than done.

So go use fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qmsjo3L7/

Insert in the second input a wrong hex, like (wekdne).

You got the error **Must be a valid hex**.

If you click over the submit button you can see that the errors are recognized

```
1) This field is required.
2) Must be a valid hex
```

but the inputs colors are red for the normal method (input a) and green for the custom method.

Also, if you edit the inputs, the custom method works when the input is changed (keyup or keydown, I don't know) but the normal method works only on submit.

There's someone more able than me that can solve this?

Click on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `<script>` block adds an additional submithandler which is causing odd results. Remove that and things immediately improve.

Bootstrap usage is demonstrated at https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/demo/bootstrap/index-bs4.html, and live demo available at https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/bootstrap/index.html

Implement the `errorElement`, `errorPlacement`, `highlight` and `unhighlight` directives shown in the above demo and it works as you expect:
https://jsfiddle.net/bytestream/dekzfxns/2/

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWW an answer directly from the creator of the jquery-validator. He has reply @[this](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2441). You're the King MAAAAAAAAAN. I've to try it. Just why you're the creator your answer it's what it solves the problem. But wait a minute. I'll try and you goes on top 

Comment: I was forced to correcting the behavior adding [this](https://jsfiddle.net/np4g176s/) script and this css @ end of file. Now it's perfect what i wanted. Just a thing. Explain in the documentation on your site more comprehensively this things about `errorElement: "em"`, and the `invalid-feedback` with the `errorPlacement` directive (the error it's placed in the same place where was at beginning ). I suggest also to use as default the em and label for choiche, and adding `highlight`and `unhighlight` in directly in your code. It would be simpler 4 the users 